# Use value of passwordbox as to a variable

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

i have a password box and i want to get the input data to check for verification.

My passwordbox c# code

```
  public void textBox2_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        //pass = textBox2.ToString();
    }
```

and the xaml code

```
<PasswordBox Name="textBox2" 
             PasswordChar="*"  
             TextInput="textBox2_TextInput" />
```

this is what i have written to capture the password

```
  private void loginbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       usr = textBox1.Text;
       SecureString passdat =textBox2.SecurePassword;
       pass = passdat.ToString();
   }
```

it returns null.This is a dummy demo so no encryption is required.I was using a text box earlier and the verification worked.using a password box just complicated things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SecureString class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) doesn't allow you to see the value; that's the whole point of it. If you want to be able to work with the value entered into the PasswordBox, use the Password member of PasswordBox instead of the SecurePassword member:

```
private void loginbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    usr = textBox1.Text;
    String pass = textBox2.Password;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that SecureString has no members that inspect, compare, or convert the value of a SecureString. The absence of such members helps protect the value of the instance from accidental or malicious exposure. Use appropriate members of the System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal class, such as the SecureStringToBSTR method, to manipulate the value of a SecureString object.

```
        private void loginbutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            usr = textBox1.Text;
            txtPassword=textBox2.Text;

            SecureString objSecureString=new SecureString();
            char[] passwordChar = txtPassword.ToCharArray();
            foreach (char c in passwordChar)
                    objSecureString.AppendChar(c);
            objSecureString.MakeReadOnly();//Notice at the end that the MakeReadOnly command prevents the SecureString to be edited any further.


            //Reading a SecureString is more complicated. There is no simple ToString method, which is also intended to keep the data secure. To read the data C# developers must access the data in memory directly. Luckily the .NET Framework makes it fairly simple:
            IntPtr stringPointer = Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(objSecureString);
            string normalString = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(stringPointer);//Original Password text

        }
```